# Pandas align multiindex dataframe with other with regular index

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, alignment, dataframe

I have one dataframe, let's call it `df1`, with a a MultiIndex (just a snippet, there are many more columns and rows)

```
                                             M1_01  M1_02  M1_03  M1_04  M1_05
Eventloc                  Exonloc                                             
chr10:52619746-52623793|- 52622648-52622741      0      0      0      0      0
chr19:58859211-58865080|+ 58864686-58864827      0      0      0      0      0
                          58864686-58864840      0      0      0      0      0
                          58864744-58864840      0      0      0      0      0
chr19:58863054-58863649|- 58863463-58863550      0      0      0      0      0
```

And another dataframe, let's go with the creative name `df2`, like this (these are the results of different algorithms, which is why they have different indices). The columns are the same, though in the first df they are not sorted.

```
                                                                                  M1_01  M1_02  M1_03  M1_04  M1_05
chr3:53274267:53274364:-@chr3:53271813:53271836:-@chr3:53268999:53269190:-         0.02    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
chr2:9002720:9002852:-@chr2:9002401:9002452:-@chr2:9000743:9000894:-               0.04    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
chr1:160192441:160192571:-@chr1:160190249:160190481:-@chr1:160188639:160188758:-    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
chr7:100473194:100473333:+@chr7:100478317:100478390:+@chr7:100478906:100479034:+    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
chr11:57182088:57182204:-@chr11:57177408:57177594:-@chr11:57176648:57176771:-       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

And I have this dataframe, again let's be creative and call it `df3`, which unifies the indices of `df1` and `df2`:

```
                                                                                                    Eventloc              Exonloc
event_id                                                                                                                         
chr3:53274267:53274364:-@chr3:53271813:53271836:-@chr3:53268999:53269190:-          chr3:53269191-53274267|-    53271812-53271836
chr2:9002720:9002852:-@chr2:9002401:9002452:-@chr2:9000743:9000894:-                  chr2:9000895-9002720|-      9002400-9002452
chr1:160192441:160192571:-@chr1:160190249:160190481:-@chr1:160188639:160188758:-  chr1:160188759-160192441|-  160190248-160190481
chr7:100473194:100473333:+@chr7:100478317:100478390:+@chr7:100478906:100479034:+  chr7:100473334-100478906|+  100478316-100478390
chr4:55124924:55124984:+@chr4:55127262:55127579:+@chr4:55129834:55130094:+          chr4:55124985-55129834|+    55127261-55127579
```

I need to do a 1:1 comparison of these results, so I tried doing both

```
df1.ix[df3.head().values]
```

and

```
df1.ix[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df3.head().values.tolist(), names=['Eventloc', 'Exonloc'])]
```

But they both give me dataframes of NAs. The only thing that works is:

```
event_id = df2.index[0]
df1.ix[df3.ix[event_id]]
```

But this obviously suboptimal as it is not vectorized and very slow. I think I'm missing some critical concept of MultiIndexes.

Thanks,
Olga

Comment: Could you try `df1.ix[pd.Index(df3.head().values)]`? I think that might work for you.

Comment: Somehow that still doesn't work, even though I've double- and triple-checked the IDs.

Comment: Actually, yes it worked!! My whole issue was that I created `df1` by resetting the index of another dataframe and I only took the `head()` and that's why I wasn't getting any of the overlap.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are doing, you need to either explicity construct the tuples (they must be fully qualifiied tuples though, e.g. have a value for EACH level), or easier, construct a boolean indexer)

```
In [7]: df1 = DataFrame(0,index=MultiIndex.from_product([list('abc'),[range(2)]]),columns=['A'])

In [8]: df1
Out[8]: 
     A
a 0  0
b 1  0
c 0  0

[3 rows x 1 columns]

In [9]: df1 = DataFrame(0,index=MultiIndex.from_product([list('abc'),list(range(2))]),columns=['A'])

In [10]: df1
Out[10]: 
     A
a 0  0
  1  0
b 0  0
  1  0
c 0  0
  1  0

[6 rows x 1 columns]

In [11]: df3 = DataFrame(0,index=['a','b'],columns=['A'])

In [12]: df3
Out[12]: 
   A
a  0
b  0

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

These are all the values of level 0 in the first frame

```
In [13]: df1.index.get_level_values(level=0)
Out[13]: Index([u'a', u'a', u'b', u'b', u'c', u'c'], dtype='object')
```

Construct a boolean indexer of the result

```
In [14]: df1.index.get_level_values(level=0).isin(df3.index)
Out[14]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [15]: df1.loc[df1.index.get_level_values(level=0).isin(df3.index)]
Out[15]: 
     A
a 0  0
  1  0
b 0  0
  1  0

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```